# "Quota limit Exceed" ,I want to understand what is "Unit" and "Cost" explained in youtube Quota page and google console

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I am confuse between quota and cost.
Can someone please explain what is mean by below.
"Quota impact: A call to this method has a quota cost of 100 units."

[image]

[image]

I want to understand what is cost ? DO we need to pay
and what is mean by unit ?
I can see queries limit is 10000, does it mean 10000 API calls allowed with one key ?
I am accessing youtube data search API in backend.
Google console graph shows that "Query per day are - 5900" but limit is set to 10000, still i am getting 403 error in API response.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a total quota of 10000.  Each request costs something search for example costs 100.  Everytime you make a request to search (yes including pageing) you are charged 100 against your total amount.

> 10000 / 100 = 100

You can make 100 requests against search a day.

Dont set to much weight on the graph in Google developer console it is not very accurate.